# Don't allow emacs to save a buffer

Tags: buffers

So this is probably a weird question but out of muscle memory I tend to save files constantly. This becomes a slight inconvenience when I have a compilation buffer then accidentally save that. I was wondering if there was a way to disable saving a file or something for buffers like this. Thanks.

Comment: Not too clear to me just what you're doing. Maybe show a step-by-step recipe. If the buffer is not associated with a file or have a file-associated mode (`auto-mode-alist`) then `C-x C-s` asks you whether to save it. Is that what you're doing - confirming to save it? If so, what is it that you want Emacs to do, to prevent you from confirming? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Something like this, perhaps:

```el
(defun my-save-buffer (&optional arg)
  "Like `save-buffer', but does nothing in certain modes."
  (interactive "p")
  (unless (derived-mode-p 'compilation-mode
                          'help-mode
                          ;; etc...
                          )
    (save-buffer arg)))

(global-set-key [remap save-buffer] #'my-save-buffer)
```